# How to add TimeZone to DateTime.UtcNow?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a TimeZone received from customer and I use it to set expiration DateTime so that it is UTC equivalent of "End of Month" in customer's time zone.

I tried this:

```
var current = timezone.ToUniversalTime(DateTime.UtcNow);
```

But could not manage to work. Can anybody help me with that?

Comment: can you show what info is in your timezone object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
DateTime utcTime = new DateTime(2016,2,10,10,15,00);
var tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Your Time Zone");
var tzTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTime, tz);
//To get time in UTC
var utcTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(tzTime, tz);
```